# Добавление в сервис несколько реализаций одного интерфейса через DI Asp net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

У меня есть интерфейс IRepository, который реализуют три класса Repository1, Repository2, Repository3. Использую dependency injection ASP NET Core для добавления этих репозиториев в контроллеры и сервисы, через конструктор. К примеру для конструктора класса SomeService такая сигнатура: public SomeService(IRepository repository). Как мне грамотно сделать так чтобы можно было добавлять в один сервис больше одной реализации интерфейса IRepository? Чтобы в каком-либо методе можно было обратиться к Repository1 и Repository2

Comment: Ждите Net8, там из коробки подвезут keyed сервисы, можно будет регистрировать несколько имплементаций с определенными ключами и по ключу брать нужные. Либо используйте сторонний DI

Comment: Как вариант, вместо нескольких _IRepository_ передавать в сервис фабрику: `public SomeService(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)`. Вообще же, если требуется несколько реализаций в одном сервисе, то стоит задуматься - не нарушает ли сервис принцип единственной обязанности.

Answer (score 5):

Регистрируйте в DI несколько имплементаций для одного интерфейса, потом внедряйте `IEnumerable<IRepository>`, получите коллекцию с сервисами в том же порядке, в котором они были зарегистрированы.

Но, если честно, такой подход вызывает вопрос: точно ли `IRepository` хороший интерфейс для регистрации, если потом по нему требуется доставать несколько имплементаций? Может быть, стоит вдобавок к сильно общей генерализации `IRepository` добавить интерфейсы под конкретные бизнес-сущности/кейсы и доставать из DI именно то, что нужно?

Просто обычно внедрение `IEnumerable<T>` используется, когда нужно осуществить какую-нибудь конвейерную обработку: внедряется несколько процессоров/визиторов, и каждый из них последовательно в порядке регистрации что-то делает.

Answer (score 5):

В .NET 8 появилась новая механика, так называемые [Keyed Services](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/net-8-dependency-injection-changes-keyed-services), которая довольно круто упрощает всю эту задачу. Раньше при регистрации несколько сервисов под одним интерфейсом мы могли только взять их коллекцию, что заставляло городить лишний код, лишние интерфейсы, что с одной стороны хорошо, но с другой, не всегда это актуально в контексте текущего проекта. Теперь мы можем задать зарегистрированному типу уникальный "ключ", по которому уже сможем без труда забрать нужный нам объект.

**Простой пример:**

```
public interface ILogger {}

public class FileLogger : ILogger {}
public class ServerLogger : ILogger {}
```

Простые два класса реализующие один интерфейс, мы их регистрируем в контейнере:

```
builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<ILogger, FileLogger>("File");
builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<ILogger, ServerLogger>("Server");
```

Как видите, обычная регистрация, разница лишь в том, что мы вызываем не `.AddScoped()`, `.AddSingleton()`, `.AddTransient()` а `.AddKeyedScoped()`, `.AddKeyedSingleton()`, `.AddKeyedTransient()`, которые дополнительно принимают еще и ключ в виде строки.

Ну и при получении нужного типа мы можем сделать уже к примеру такое:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass([FromKeyedServices("File")] ILogger fileLogger, [FromKeyedServices("Server")] ILogger serverLogger) {  }
}
```

При помощи простого атрибута мы запрашиваем у контейнера уже нужный нам тип их того списка, что был зарегистрирован ранее.

Comment: Стоило добавить, что NET 8 еще официально не вышел и находится в стадии разработки на данный момент времени

Comment: @OwDafuq Не вижу смысла. Поясню... Вопрос про то, как сделать то-то, а не про то, как установить .NET и на какой он стадии. К тому-же, .NET8 на данный момент на стадии RC, а это означает то, что он очень скоро выйдет, и уже сейчас можно (и нужно) брать его для разработки новых проектов. Другое, не менее важно, вот напишу, через условный месяц релиз, кто будет исправлять вопрос? Я вот не хочу, сообщество думаю тоже не будет. Так нужна-ли данная информация в вопросе? Или тут важно лишь то, что данная фича доступна с конкретной версии?